# byte y=y+x; Results in error but y+=x; Compiles successfully. Why?

Tags: java, byte, short

In Java there's a problem when we are using either byte or short data type.

```
byte y=19;
byte x=10;
y=y+x; //Compile Error:
System.out.println(y);
```

Here the output of this program.

```
error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
```

But when we use x+=1, it won't generate any compile error.

```
byte y=19;
byte x=10;
y+=x; //No Errors !?    
System.out.println(y);
```

Output is `29`

Is there a different between `x=x+1` and `x+=1`using either byte or short data type?

Comment: maybe because in the first version it's trying to cast y into a byte but in the second it casts both x and y to ints